# Order divs based on dates inside a span element

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 divs which I would like to order dynamically based on the date inside the **span** tag. I would like it to appear from **newest** to **oldest**.  What's the best way to achieve this using JQuery?

```
<div class="mydivs">Some description goes here <span>05/03/09</span></div>

<div class="mydivs">Some description goes here <span>01/15/11</span></div>

<div class="mydivs">Some description goes here <span>12/25/07</span></div>

<div class="mydivs">Some description goes here <span>09/25/11</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**See example of the following here →**](http://jsfiddle.net/WSetb/1/)

```
var amd = [],
    tDate, tElem;

$('.mydivs').each(function(i, elem) {
    var aDate = $(this).children('span').text().split('/');
    $(this).data('date', aDate[2] + aDate[1] + aDate[0]);
});

amd = $('.mydivs').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('date');
}).get();

amd.sort();

while (amd.length) {
    tDate = amd.pop();
    tElem = $('.mydivs').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('date') == tDate;
    }).detach();
    $('#wrapper').append(tElem);
}
```

That was fun!

Answer (score 0):

There's [this great plugin for Sorting Elements with jQuery](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/sortElements/).

Or you can do it by hand.  Doing it by hand would involve something like this:

```
var toSort = new Array();
$('div.mydivs').each(function (divIndex, divElement) {
    toSort[$(divElement).first('span').text()] = $(divElement.html());
});
```

With that, you'd have a hashtable of all your divs and you can sort the keys, delete the original divs and re-append them in the right order.